# append jquery mobile datebox using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have form that I want to append in a div using jquery , within this form I want to append the jquery mobile datebox

how can I append the datebox within the form in a correct syntax?

```
$('#PersonalInfo').append(
 '<form id="registerForm" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+

 '<label for="mode2">DateBox</label>'+
 '<input name="mode2" id="mode2" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-  options='{"mode":"datebox", "useNewStyle":true}' />'+
'<input type="submit" value="save" id="submitButton">'+
'</form>');
```

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Here is a **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bM72z/1/)**

You need to escape the single quotes around the options, set type="date" on the input, and also re-trigger the page creation in jQM.  In the example below, I have a page with id="page1".  In the pageinit event, I add the dynamic form (with escaped quotes) and then call trigger('create') on the page:

```
$("#page1").on("pageinit", function(){

    $('#PersonalInfo').append(
      '<form id="registerForm" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
      '<label for="mode2">DateBox</label>'+
      '<input name="mode2" id="mode2" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options=\'{"mode":"datebox", "useNewStyle":true }\' />'+
      '<input type="submit" value="save" id="submitButton">'+
      '</form>');

    $('#page1').trigger('create');    
});
```

Comment: this works fine the datebox appears but without it's design?!

Comment: Works fine for me, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bM72z/1/, check that you are loading the datebox libraries in the correct place and order, etc.

Comment: Also, make sure type="date" on the input instead of type="text".